# Why is typescript assigning any to a type that is clearly defined?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a class that houses all the rules associated with an object. All rules have a specific function signature:

```
type ruleFunction = (dev: Developer, utilites:utilitesType) => boolean;

class Developer {
  test: string;
}

interface utilitesType {
  markRule:  (this: _Rule, result: boolean) => {

  }
}
```

However when I use this interface in my class:

```
class rules implements Record<keyof rules, ruleFunction> {
    age(dev,util) {
        util. //no intelisense
    }
}
```

After further investigation it seems that vs code is marking the types of the parameters as any and the return type as void. (please see the screenshot below)The weird thing is that it should infer the types from the interface, how can I fix this?[image: screenie]

Comment: The two pieces of code don't seem to be related, where is `Record` defined?

Comment: Record is a built in typescript utility type, documentation is here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Answer (score 1):

By not declaring the types of the member parameters, you are basically declaring them implicitly as "any".

You're also not returning anything so the return type can't be inferred.

You have to use the correct function prototype which conforms with the "ruleFunction" that you have specified.

This works:

```
class rules implements Record<keyof rules, ruleFunction>
{
    age(dev: Developer, utilities: utilitesType): boolean
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, however this also works  const test: ruleFunction = (dev, utils) => { //intelisense for parameters work here because it is inferred from the type
 
} why do I not have to define it there but when I use it in a class I do. I there a better way?

Comment: That doesn't work..

`TS2322: Type '(dev: Developer, utils: utilitesType) => void' is not assignable to type 'ruleFunction'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

Comment: This will work: `const test: ruleFunction = (dev, utils): boolean => { }` because you've *already given it the type* `ruleFunction` so it knows what you intend to do

Comment: Im giving it the type rule function as a parameter of the Record interface.

Comment: Remember, in your class, you are *declaring a new property* and that property has to conform to the interface.  With the `const test ruleFunction etc..` you are assigning a value to an already defined type.

Comment: Okay, so I what I'm getting is that this might be the wrong way to do this, How can I assign the type of every key in this class to ruleFunction?

Comment: You could declare it like this?

`const obj: {[key: string]: ruleFunction} = {}`

This object will now only allow ruleFunctions to be assigned to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219562/discussion-between-raphael-castro-and-tom-mettam).